# phpunit selenium2 - select multiple elements

Tags: php, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I have a lot of 'h2' elements with 'a' inside.
All I want is just get all the 'a' in the 'h2'

when I try something like this:

```
 public function testBreakingNewsH2(){

    $this->url('index.php');

    $h2Elements = $this->byCssSelector('h2')->byCssSelector('a')->text();
    $this->assertEquals('Breaking News', $h2Elements);
}
```

I get only the first 'a' inside 'h2'.
I need to check that all 'h2' links are exists (get all 'h2' elements that contains 'a')
I tried something like this:

public function testHomePgaeH2(){

```
    $this->url('index.php');
    $h2Elements = $this->elements($this->using('css selector')->value('h2'));

    $this->assertContains('Breaking News', $h2Elements);
    $this->assertContains('Analysis', $h2Elements);
    $this->assertContains('Calendar', $h2Elements);
    $this->assertContains('Studies', $h2Elements);
```

}

this not works, this is the best example that I found for my issue.
of course I can try something like this:

```
$this->assrtRegExp('/xxxx/i', $this->source());
```

but I want make it clean as possible without taking all the source.

please advise,
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a list of elements by css selector with this code:

```
$elements = $this->elements($this->using('css selector')->value('h2 a'));
foreach ($elements as $i=>$element){
    echo $element->text() . "\n";
}
```

If you want to check that all `h2` contain `a`, you can find all elements by css selector `h2` and count them then find by `h2 a` and count again. Then compare. Also you can iterate all `h2 a` elements and check their urls by array or regexp. It depends on what you want.

Comment: thanks. maybe u know how can I check specific link name with assertContains for example I want check if "Breaking News" is a link inside the h2 in my site. the problem is if I put assertEqual into foreach it will failure. when I try ` $this->assertContains('Breaking News', $h2Elements); ` it says: Failed asserting that an array contains 'Breaking News'

Comment: Make an array: $titles[] = $element->text(); (in foreach) then do $this->assertContains('Breaking News', $titles);

Comment: thanks, I so stupid it amazing I forgot that I can use regular php.